# Is AWS Federated Identities necessary if the only AWS resource a user interacts with is API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, api-gateway

I am currently investigating the use of Federated Identities and from the many examples I have read, it seems to be a way to grant users temporary credentials to various AWS services. For my case, the API Gateway is all that the user will interact with, since the API server is the one making calls to other services like S3 and DynamoDB. I like how permissions are controlled using IAM, but I'm failing to see any other appeals of Federated Identities. User Pools itself already supports password/fb/google/etc sign in, the only downside I see with user pools is that I'll need to do the authorization manually in the API layer. Is there something else I am missing with Federated Identities? Is it worth it given my use of only API Gateways (externally).

Comment: Have you considered [API Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) if you want some sort of control over who can invoke the api?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also have a frontend vue app that users will authenticate themself. So API key won't work in this case

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the way that you will secure your API Gateway endpoint.

If you secure your API using AWS IAM, you'll need a way to convert your authentication tokens in AWS IAM Roles. For that scenario you can use AWS Cognito Idp (not the User Pool) or AWS Federated Identities. The difference is: using AWS IAM Federated Identities you will need to call AWS STS AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity in your frontend code. If you use AWS Cognito Idp this is done for you. . (AWS strongly suggest that you use the Cognito Idp in that scenario)

If you secure your API using [AWS Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) you don't need to use AWS Federated Identities. You can connect API Gateway directly to AWS Cognito and the service will enforce the controls for you. In that case you'll need to have a Cognito User Pool.

You also have a choice to use [Custom Authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html). In that scenario you will implement a lambda function that will evaluate your request and decide if it is authorized or not. In the same way, you won't need federated identities.

And finally you have the API Key authorization, that you already mentioned that is not applicable to your use case.